# How do I check for a Dictionary Type in Elixir

Tags: elixir

I want to check if the type of a parameter given to a function in Elixir is a Dictionary. How do I do this?

Answer (score 2):

First you have to be aware that Elixir supports 2 Dictionary types

- Erlangs native Map type (for maps with only limited items)
  `map = %{}`
- Elixirs own Dictionary type (dictionaries with a potentially large payload)
  `dict = HashDict.new`

Both types however need to be checked with Erlangs native `:erlang.is_map`.

```
def some_fun(arg) when :erlang.is_map(arg) do
    #do your thing
end
```

More info can be found under sections 7.2 and 7.3 (http://elixir-lang.org/getting_started/7.html)

Comment: HashDict will return true to :erlang.is_map/1 just because it's a struct. You will get true for example if you run :erlang.is_map(%URI{}). URI is a struct also, but it will return true.

If you want to check if it's a HashDict you should pattern match on it with something like this:

def some_fun(arg = %HashDict{}), do: ...

You can see more here: https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/master/lib/elixir/lib/hash_dict.ex#L40